# WS02 Identity Server 6.0 for challenge questions rest API

Tags: wso2-identity-server

At present for challenge question rest API which is present in version 6.0 https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/apis/challenge-rest-api/#/ we are having question sets and each of the sets are having certain number of questions. Is there any way of creating, retrieving and updating individual questions instead of sets concept?

Comment: Have you created/updated the questions independent of question sets in previous IS versions using SOAP API / management console? If so add the steps you followed to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can add question sets with a single question. Refer to the answer in here https://stackoverflow.com/a/73896377/15082730