# Rest API for replacement of challenge questions SOAP API in WSO2 version 6.0

Tags: wso2-identity-server

This is an extension for [WS02 Identity Server 6.0 for challenge questions rest API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73891783/ws02-identity-server-6-0-for-challenge-questions-rest-api) question

Step1: In our project, we are currently using wso2 version 5.10

Step2: We are using challenge questions mentioned in this location[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gt5Vl.png)
We are adding local claims of all those 8 questions[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBgpu.png). Here we are not using any set concept, we are giving individual questions.

Step3: We are using UserIdentityManagementAdminService.wsdl for challenge questions. We are using getAllChallengeQuestions, setChallengeQuestionsOfUser and getChallengeQuestionsOfUser SOAP API's for retrieving and updating those security questions mentioned in the above location.

Now we are planning to upgrade the WSO2 version from 5.10 to 6.0. In version 6.0, they are suggesting to use rest API's instead of SOAP API's. So Is there any rest API available in version 6.0 for the replacement of getAllChallengeQuestions, setChallengeQuestionsOfUser and getChallengeQuestionsOfUser SOAP API's?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to create new **Question sets with just one question** and manage to achieve this. To create the sets I used the old carbon console (https://localhost:9443/carbon) and navigated to `Main>Manage<Challenge Questions>Add Challenge Question Set`. Make sure to set the language of the questions correctly.

After doing that I used [/me/challenges](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/apis/challenge-rest-api/#/me/getChallengesForLoggedInUser) to get all the questions and I could see all the sets with exactly one question each. Then you can use `PUT` and `POST` [APIs](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/apis/challenge-rest-api/#/me) in the `ME` section to update the answers.

Comment: I have another question..I want to use https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/apis/challenge-rest-api/#/ rest API's for retrieving the questions stored in /_system/config/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt/questionCollection. Will these rest API's work for retrieving those questions or else do we have any other rest API's for retrieving those questions?